# Antminer S9 13.5Th/s Jan 2018 batch gives a zeros hash rate but works with the pool normally

Tags: antminer

I have a strange thing with my Antminer S9 which I just received from Bitmain couple of weeks ago, after few hours of working suddenly I find the hash rate comes to zeros, however it's working perfect with the pool and gives me my rewards normally.
I got the log here, long but experts of course can help:

```
asic[00]=911    asic[01]=911    asic[02]=911    asic[03]=911    asic[04]=910    asic[05]=909    asic[06]=911    asic[07]=910    
asic[08]=910    asic[09]=910    asic[10]=910    asic[11]=907    asic[12]=908    asic[13]=908    asic[14]=906    asic[15]=908    
asic[16]=909    asic[17]=905    asic[18]=906    asic[19]=907    asic[20]=905    asic[21]=906    asic[22]=906    asic[23]=906    
asic[24]=907    asic[25]=908    asic[26]=908    asic[27]=907    asic[28]=907    asic[29]=907    asic[30]=906    asic[31]=907    
asic[32]=907    asic[33]=908    asic[34]=908    asic[35]=908    asic[36]=909    asic[37]=904    asic[38]=907    asic[39]=908    
asic[40]=906    asic[41]=907    asic[42]=908    asic[43]=908    asic[44]=906    asic[45]=909    asic[46]=909    asic[47]=907    
asic[48]=906    asic[49]=908    asic[50]=905    asic[51]=908    asic[52]=907    asic[53]=908    asic[54]=908    asic[55]=907    
asic[56]=906    asic[57]=909    asic[58]=910    asic[59]=910    asic[60]=908    asic[61]=909    asic[62]=909    


Below ASIC's core didn't receive all the nonce, they should receive 8 nonce each!

asic[00]=911
core[035]=7 

asic[01]=911
core[015]=7 

asic[02]=911
core[099]=7 

asic[03]=911
core[099]=7 

asic[04]=910
core[064]=7 core[099]=7 

asic[05]=909
core[072]=7 core[099]=7 core[106]=7 

asic[06]=911
core[099]=7 

asic[07]=910
core[099]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[08]=910
core[099]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[09]=910
core[099]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[10]=910
core[099]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[11]=907
core[021]=7 core[041]=7 core[099]=7 core[106]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[12]=908
core[037]=7 core[041]=7 core[099]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[13]=908
core[041]=7 core[049]=7 core[099]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[14]=906
core[023]=7 core[049]=7 core[060]=7 core[067]=7 core[073]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[15]=908
core[049]=7 core[051]=7 core[073]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[16]=909
core[049]=7 core[073]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[17]=905
core[023]=7 core[027]=7 core[049]=7 core[051]=7 core[073]=7 core[082]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[18]=906
core[023]=7 core[049]=7 core[073]=7 core[077]=7 core[082]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[19]=907
core[023]=7 core[049]=7 core[073]=7 core[077]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[20]=905
core[023]=7 core[049]=7 core[071]=7 core[073]=7 core[077]=7 core[082]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[21]=906
core[023]=7 core[049]=7 core[071]=7 core[073]=7 core[082]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[22]=906
core[023]=7 core[049]=7 core[071]=7 core[073]=7 core[082]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[23]=906
core[023]=7 core[049]=7 core[071]=7 core[073]=7 core[082]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[24]=907
core[023]=7 core[049]=7 core[071]=7 core[073]=7 core[082]=7 

asic[25]=908
core[023]=7 core[049]=7 core[071]=7 core[073]=7 

asic[26]=908
core[023]=7 core[049]=7 core[071]=7 core[073]=7 

asic[27]=907
core[015]=7 core[023]=7 core[071]=7 core[073]=7 core[082]=7 

asic[28]=907
core[015]=7 core[071]=7 core[073]=7 core[082]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[29]=907
core[071]=7 core[072]=7 core[073]=7 core[082]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[30]=906
core[015]=7 core[023]=7 core[036]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[31]=907
core[015]=7 core[023]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[32]=907
core[015]=7 core[036]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[33]=908
core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[104]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[34]=908
core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[104]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[35]=908
core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[104]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[36]=909
core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[104]=7 

asic[37]=904
core[053]=4 core[071]=7 core[072]=7 core[082]=7 core[104]=7 

asic[38]=907
core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[090]=7 core[104]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[39]=908
core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[104]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[40]=906
core[014]=7 core[070]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[104]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[41]=907
core[070]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[104]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[42]=908
core[070]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[43]=908
core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[110]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[44]=906
core[003]=7 core[070]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[111]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[45]=909
core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[46]=909
core[020]=7 core[071]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[47]=907
core[020]=7 core[039]=7 core[054]=7 core[071]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[48]=906
core[020]=7 core[039]=7 core[070]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[49]=908
core[039]=7 core[071]=7 core[111]=7 core[112]=7 

asic[50]=905
core[020]=7 core[039]=7 core[070]=6 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[51]=908
core[039]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[52]=907
core[038]=7 core[042]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[53]=908
core[038]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[54]=908
core[038]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[55]=907
core[009]=7 core[038]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[56]=906
core[009]=7 core[037]=7 core[038]=7 core[071]=7 core[082]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[57]=909
core[038]=7 core[071]=7 core[111]=7 

asic[58]=910
core[038]=7 core[071]=7 

asic[59]=910
core[038]=7 core[071]=7 

asic[60]=908
core[038]=7 core[054]=7 core[070]=7 core[071]=7 

asic[61]=909
core[038]=7 core[070]=7 core[071]=7 

asic[62]=909
core[038]=7 core[070]=7 core[071]=7 



freq[00]=606    freq[01]=606    freq[02]=606    freq[03]=606    freq[04]=606    freq[05]=606    freq[06]=606    freq[07]=606    
freq[08]=606    freq[09]=606    freq[10]=606    freq[11]=606    freq[12]=606    freq[13]=606    freq[14]=606    freq[15]=606    
freq[16]=606    freq[17]=606    freq[18]=606    freq[19]=606    freq[20]=606    freq[21]=606    freq[22]=606    freq[23]=606    
freq[24]=606    freq[25]=606    freq[26]=606    freq[27]=606    freq[28]=606    freq[29]=606    freq[30]=606    freq[31]=606    
freq[32]=606    freq[33]=606    freq[34]=606    freq[35]=606    freq[36]=606    freq[37]=606    freq[38]=606    freq[39]=606    
freq[40]=606    freq[41]=606    freq[42]=606    freq[43]=606    freq[44]=606    freq[45]=606    freq[46]=606    freq[47]=606    
freq[48]=606    freq[49]=606    freq[50]=606    freq[51]=606    freq[52]=606    freq[53]=606    freq[54]=606    freq[55]=606    
freq[56]=606    freq[57]=606    freq[58]=606    freq[59]=606    freq[60]=606    freq[61]=606    freq[62]=606    

total valid nonce number:57195
total send work number:57456
require valid nonce number:57456
repeated_nonce_num:0
err_nonce_num:24799
last_nonce_num:21509
get nonces on chain[6]
require nonce number:912
require validnonce number:57456
asic[00]=912    asic[01]=912    asic[02]=912    asic[03]=912    asic[04]=912    asic[05]=912    asic[06]=912    asic[07]=912    
asic[08]=912    asic[09]=912    asic[10]=912    asic[11]=912    asic[12]=912    asic[13]=912    asic[14]=912    asic[15]=912    
asic[16]=912    asic[17]=912    asic[18]=912    asic[19]=912    asic[20]=912    asic[21]=912    asic[22]=912    asic[23]=912    
asic[24]=912    asic[25]=912    asic[26]=912    asic[27]=912    asic[28]=912    asic[29]=912    asic[30]=912    asic[31]=912    
asic[32]=912    asic[33]=912    asic[34]=912    asic[35]=912    asic[36]=912    asic[37]=912    asic[38]=912    asic[39]=912    
asic[40]=912    asic[41]=912    asic[42]=912    asic[43]=912    asic[44]=912    asic[45]=912    asic[46]=912    asic[47]=912    
asic[48]=912    asic[49]=912    asic[50]=912    asic[51]=912    asic[52]=912    asic[53]=912    asic[54]=912    asic[55]=912    
asic[56]=912    asic[57]=912    asic[58]=912    asic[59]=912    asic[60]=912    asic[61]=912    asic[62]=912    


Below ASIC's core didn't receive all the nonce, they should receive 8 nonce each!



freq[00]=643    freq[01]=643    freq[02]=643    freq[03]=643    freq[04]=643    freq[05]=643    freq[06]=643    freq[07]=643    
freq[08]=643    freq[09]=650    freq[10]=650    freq[11]=650    freq[12]=650    freq[13]=650    freq[14]=650    freq[15]=650    
freq[16]=650    freq[17]=650    freq[18]=650    freq[19]=650    freq[20]=650    freq[21]=650    freq[22]=650    freq[23]=650    
freq[24]=650    freq[25]=650    freq[26]=650    freq[27]=650    freq[28]=650    freq[29]=650    freq[30]=650    freq[31]=650    
freq[32]=650    freq[33]=650    freq[34]=650    freq[35]=650    freq[36]=650    freq[37]=650    freq[38]=650    freq[39]=650    
freq[40]=650    freq[41]=650    freq[42]=650    freq[43]=650    freq[44]=650    freq[45]=650    freq[46]=650    freq[47]=650    
freq[48]=650    freq[49]=650    freq[50]=650    freq[51]=650    freq[52]=650    freq[53]=650    freq[54]=650    freq[55]=650    
freq[56]=650    freq[57]=650    freq[58]=650    freq[59]=650    freq[60]=650    freq[61]=650    freq[62]=650    

total valid nonce number:57456
total send work number:57456
require valid nonce number:57456
repeated_nonce_num:0
err_nonce_num:26569
last_nonce_num:28633
get nonces on chain[7]
require nonce number:912
require validnonce number:57456
asic[00]=912    asic[01]=912    asic[02]=912    asic[03]=912    asic[04]=912    asic[05]=912    asic[06]=912    asic[07]=912    
asic[08]=912    asic[09]=912    asic[10]=912    asic[11]=912    asic[12]=911    asic[13]=912    asic[14]=912    asic[15]=912    
asic[16]=912    asic[17]=912    asic[18]=912    asic[19]=912    asic[20]=912    asic[21]=912    asic[22]=912    asic[23]=912    
asic[24]=912    asic[25]=912    asic[26]=912    asic[27]=912    asic[28]=912    asic[29]=912    asic[30]=912    asic[31]=912    
asic[32]=912    asic[33]=912    asic[34]=912    asic[35]=911    asic[36]=912    asic[37]=912    asic[38]=912    asic[39]=912    
asic[40]=912    asic[41]=912    asic[42]=912    asic[43]=912    asic[44]=912    asic[45]=912    asic[46]=912    asic[47]=912    
asic[48]=912    asic[49]=911    asic[50]=912    asic[51]=912    asic[52]=912    asic[53]=911    asic[54]=912    asic[55]=912    
asic[56]=912    asic[57]=912    asic[58]=912    asic[59]=912    asic[60]=912    asic[61]=912    asic[62]=912    


Below ASIC's core didn't receive all the nonce, they should receive 8 nonce each!

asic[12]=911
core[008]=7 

asic[35]=911
core[079]=7 

asic[49]=911
core[016]=7 

asic[53]=911
core[088]=7 



freq[00]=656    freq[01]=656    freq[02]=656    freq[03]=656    freq[04]=656    freq[05]=656    freq[06]=656    freq[07]=656    
freq[08]=656    freq[09]=656    freq[10]=656    freq[11]=656    freq[12]=656    freq[13]=656    freq[14]=656    freq[15]=656    
freq[16]=656    freq[17]=656    freq[18]=656    freq[19]=656    freq[20]=656    freq[21]=656    freq[22]=656    freq[23]=656    
freq[24]=656    freq[25]=656    freq[26]=656    freq[27]=656    freq[28]=656    freq[29]=656    freq[30]=656    freq[31]=656    
freq[32]=656    freq[33]=656    freq[34]=656    freq[35]=656    freq[36]=656    freq[37]=656    freq[38]=656    freq[39]=656    
freq[40]=656    freq[41]=662    freq[42]=656    freq[43]=656    freq[44]=656    freq[45]=656    freq[46]=656    freq[47]=656    
freq[48]=656    freq[49]=656    freq[50]=662    freq[51]=662    freq[52]=662    freq[53]=662    freq[54]=662    freq[55]=662    
freq[56]=662    freq[57]=662    freq[58]=662    freq[59]=662    freq[60]=662    freq[61]=662    freq[62]=662    

total valid nonce number:57452
total send work number:57456
require valid nonce number:57456
repeated_nonce_num:0
err_nonce_num:26751
last_nonce_num:28630
chain[5]: All chip cores are opened OK!
Test Patten on chain[5]: FAILED!
chain[6]: All chip cores are opened OK!
Test Patten on chain[6]: OK!
chain[7]: All chip cores are opened OK!
Test Patten on chain[7]: FAILED!
do heat board 8xPatten for 2 times
start send works on chain[5]
start send works on chain[6]
start send works on chain[7]
PCB temp>60 will set the voltage limited on chain[6], change voltage=890
PCB temp>60 now set pic voltage=91 on chain[6]
PCB temp>60 will set the voltage limited on chain[7], change voltage=890
PCB temp>60 now set pic voltage=91 on chain[7]
get send work num :57456 on Chain[5]
get send work num :57456 on Chain[6]
get send work num :57456 on Chain[7]
wait recv nonce on chain[5]
wait recv nonce on chain[6]
wait recv nonce on chain[7]
get nonces on chain[5]
require nonce number:912
require validnonce number:57456
asic[00]=905    asic[01]=905    asic[02]=906    asic[03]=906    asic[04]=906    asic[05]=906    asic[06]=906    asic[07]=906    
asic[08]=906    asic[09]=906    asic[10]=906    asic[11]=906    asic[12]=907    asic[13]=907    asic[14]=907    asic[15]=907    
asic[16]=907    asic[17]=907    asic[18]=907    asic[19]=907    asic[20]=906    asic[21]=907    asic[22]=907    asic[23]=907    
asic[24]=907    asic[25]=907    asic[26]=907    asic[27]=907    asic[28]=907    asic[29]=907    asic[30]=907    asic[31]=907    
asic[32]=907    asic[33]=907    asic[34]=907    asic[35]=907    asic[36]=907    asic[37]=907    asic[38]=907    asic[39]=907    
asic[40]=907    asic[41]=907    asic[42]=907    asic[43]=907    asic[44]=907    asic[45]=907    asic[46]=907    asic[47]=906    
asic[48]=906    asic[49]=906    asic[50]=906    asic[51]=906    asic[52]=906    asic[53]=906    asic[54]=907    asic[55]=907    
asic[56]=906    asic[57]=906    asic[58]=906    asic[59]=906    asic[60]=906    asic[61]=906    asic[62]=906    


Below ASIC's core didn't receive all the nonce, they should receive 8 nonce each!

asic[00]=905
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[054]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[01]=905
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[054]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[02]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[03]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[04]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[05]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[06]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[07]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[08]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[09]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[10]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[11]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[074]=7 

asic[12]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[13]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[14]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[15]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[16]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[17]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[18]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[19]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[20]=906
core[044]=7 core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[21]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[22]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[23]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[24]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[25]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[26]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[27]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[28]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[29]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[30]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[31]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[32]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[33]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[34]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[35]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[36]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[37]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[38]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[39]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[40]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[41]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[42]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[43]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[44]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[45]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[46]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[47]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[073]=7 

asic[48]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[073]=7 

asic[49]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[073]=7 

asic[50]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[073]=7 

asic[51]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[073]=7 

asic[52]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[073]=7 

asic[53]=906
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 core[073]=7 

asic[54]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[55]=907
core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[56]=906
core[048]=7 core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[57]=906
core[048]=7 core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[58]=906
core[048]=7 core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[59]=906
core[048]=7 core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[60]=906
core[048]=7 core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[61]=906
core[048]=7 core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 

asic[62]=906
core[048]=7 core[049]=7 core[050]=7 core[051]=7 core[052]=7 core[053]=7 



freq[00]=606    freq[01]=606    freq[02]=606    freq[03]=606    freq[04]=606    freq[05]=606    freq[06]=606    freq[07]=606    
freq[08]=606    freq[09]=606    freq[10]=606    freq[11]=606    freq[12]=606    freq[13]=606    freq[14]=606    freq[15]=606    
freq[16]=606    freq[17]=606    freq[18]=606    freq[19]=606    freq[20]=606    freq[21]=606    freq[22]=606    freq[23]=606    
freq[24]=606    freq[25]=606    freq[26]=606    freq[27]=606    freq[28]=606    freq[29]=606    freq[30]=606    freq[31]=606    
freq[32]=606    freq[33]=606    freq[34]=606    freq[35]=606    freq[36]=606    freq[37]=606    freq[38]=606    freq[39]=606    
freq[40]=606    freq[41]=606    freq[42]=606    freq[43]=606    freq[44]=606    freq[45]=606    freq[46]=606    freq[47]=606    
freq[48]=606    freq[49]=606    freq[50]=606    freq[51]=606    freq[52]=606    freq[53]=606    freq[54]=606    freq[55]=606    
freq[56]=606    freq[57]=606    freq[58]=606    freq[59]=606    freq[60]=606    freq[61]=606    freq[62]=606    

total valid nonce number:57112
total send work number:57456
require valid nonce number:57456
repeated_nonce_num:0
err_nonce_num:24772
last_nonce_num:41567
get nonces on chain[6]
require nonce number:912
require validnonce number:57456
asic[00]=912    asic[01]=912    asic[02]=912    asic[03]=912    asic[04]=912    asic[05]=912    asic[06]=912    asic[07]=912    
asic[08]=912    asic[09]=912    asic[10]=912    asic[11]=912    asic[12]=912    asic[13]=912    asic[14]=912    asic[15]=912    
asic[16]=912    asic[17]=912    asic[18]=912    asic[19]=912    asic[20]=912    asic[21]=912    asic[22]=912    asic[23]=912    
asic[24]=912    asic[25]=912    asic[26]=912    asic[27]=912    asic[28]=912    asic[29]=912    asic[30]=912    asic[31]=912    
asic[32]=912    asic[33]=912    asic[34]=912    asic[35]=912    asic[36]=912    asic[37]=912    asic[38]=912    asic[39]=912    
asic[40]=912    asic[41]=912    asic[42]=912    asic[43]=912    asic[44]=912    asic[45]=912    asic[46]=912    asic[47]=912    
asic[48]=912    asic[49]=912    asic[50]=912    asic[51]=912    asic[52]=912    asic[53]=912    asic[54]=912    asic[55]=912    
asic[56]=912    asic[57]=912    asic[58]=912    asic[59]=912    asic[60]=912    asic[61]=912    asic[62]=912    


Below ASIC's core didn't receive all the nonce, they should receive 8 nonce each!



freq[00]=643    freq[01]=643    freq[02]=643    freq[03]=643    freq[04]=643    freq[05]=643    freq[06]=643    freq[07]=643    
freq[08]=643    freq[09]=650    freq[10]=650    freq[11]=650    freq[12]=650    freq[13]=650    freq[14]=650    freq[15]=650    
freq[16]=650    freq[17]=650    freq[18]=650    freq[19]=650    freq[20]=650    freq[21]=650    freq[22]=650    freq[23]=650    
freq[24]=650    freq[25]=650    freq[26]=650    freq[27]=650    freq[28]=650    freq[29]=650    freq[30]=650    freq[31]=650    
freq[32]=650    freq[33]=650    freq[34]=650    freq[35]=650    freq[36]=650    freq[37]=650    freq[38]=650    freq[39]=650    
freq[40]=650    freq[41]=650    freq[42]=650    freq[43]=650    freq[44]=650    freq[45]=650    freq[46]=650    freq[47]=650    
freq[48]=650    freq[49]=650    freq[50]=650    freq[51]=650    freq[52]=650    freq[53]=650    freq[54]=650    freq[55]=650    
freq[56]=650    freq[57]=650    freq[58]=650    freq[59]=650    freq[60]=650    freq[61]=650    freq[62]=650    

total valid nonce number:57456
total send work number:57456
require valid nonce number:57456
repeated_nonce_num:0
err_nonce_num:26585
last_nonce_num:48700
get nonces on chain[7]
require nonce number:912
require validnonce number:57456
asic[00]=912    asic[01]=912    asic[02]=912    asic[03]=912    asic[04]=912    asic[05]=912    asic[06]=912    asic[07]=912    
asic[08]=912    asic[09]=912    asic[10]=912    asic[11]=912    asic[12]=912    asic[13]=912    asic[14]=912    asic[15]=912    
asic[16]=912    asic[17]=912    asic[18]=912    asic[19]=912    asic[20]=912    asic[21]=912    asic[22]=912    asic[23]=911    
asic[24]=912    asic[25]=912    asic[26]=912    asic[27]=912    asic[28]=912    asic[29]=912    asic[30]=912    asic[31]=912    
asic[32]=912    asic[33]=912    asic[34]=912    asic[35]=912    asic[36]=912    asic[37]=912    asic[38]=912    asic[39]=912    
asic[40]=912    asic[41]=912    asic[42]=912    asic[43]=912    asic[44]=912    asic[45]=912    asic[46]=912    asic[47]=912    
asic[48]=912    asic[49]=912    asic[50]=912    asic[51]=912    asic[52]=912    asic[53]=912    asic[54]=912    asic[55]=912    
asic[56]=911    asic[57]=912    asic[58]=912    asic[59]=912    asic[60]=912    asic[61]=912    asic[62]=912    


Below ASIC's core didn't receive all the nonce, they should receive 8 nonce each!

asic[23]=911
core[110]=7 

asic[56]=911
core[003]=7 



freq[00]=656    freq[01]=656    freq[02]=656    freq[03]=656    freq[04]=656    freq[05]=656    freq[06]=656    freq[07]=656    
freq[08]=656    freq[09]=656    freq[10]=656    freq[11]=656    freq[12]=656    freq[13]=656    freq[14]=656    freq[15]=656    
freq[16]=656    freq[17]=656    freq[18]=656    freq[19]=656    freq[20]=656    freq[21]=656    freq[22]=656    freq[23]=656    
freq[24]=656    freq[25]=656    freq[26]=656    freq[27]=656    freq[28]=656    freq[29]=656    freq[30]=656    freq[31]=656    
freq[32]=656    freq[33]=656    freq[34]=656    freq[35]=656    freq[36]=656    freq[37]=656    freq[38]=656    freq[39]=656    
freq[40]=656    freq[41]=662    freq[42]=656    freq[43]=656    freq[44]=656    freq[45]=656    freq[46]=656    freq[47]=656    
freq[48]=656    freq[49]=656    freq[50]=662    freq[51]=662    freq[52]=662    freq[53]=662    freq[54]=662    freq[55]=662    
freq[56]=662    freq[57]=662    freq[58]=662    freq[59]=662    freq[60]=662    freq[61]=662    freq[62]=662    

total valid nonce number:57454
total send work number:57456
require valid nonce number:57456
repeated_nonce_num:0
err_nonce_num:26774
last_nonce_num:62958
chain[5]: All chip cores are opened OK!
Test Patten on chain[5]: FAILED!
chain[6]: All chip cores are opened OK!
Test Patten on chain[6]: OK!
chain[7]: All chip cores are opened OK!
Test Patten on chain[7]: FAILED!
setStartTimePoint total_tv_start_sys=418 total_tv_end_sys=419
restartNum = 2 , auto-reinit enabled...
Error: set_BC_write_command wait buffer ready timeout!
Error: clement debug: wait BC ready timeout, PLUG ON=0x000000e0..
Error: set_BC_write_command wait buffer ready timeout!
Error: clement debug: wait BC ready timeout, PLUG ON=0x000000e0..
Error: set_BC_write_command wait buffer ready timeout!
Error: clement debug: wait BC ready timeout, PLUG ON=0x000000e0..
Error: set_BC_write_command wait buffer ready timeout!
Error: clement debug: wait BC ready timeout, PLUG ON=0x000000e0..
Error: check_asic_reg 0x08 timeout
Error: set_BC_write_command wait buffer ready timeout!
Error: clement debug: wait BC ready timeout, PLUG ON=0x000000e0..
Error: set_BC_write_command wait buffer ready timeout!
Error: clement debug: wait BC ready timeout, PLUG ON=0x000000e0..
Error: check_asic_reg 0x08 timeout
do read_temp_func once...
do check_asic_reg 0x08

get RT hashrate from Chain[5]: (asic index start from 1-63)
Asic[01]=34762157.476000 Asic[02]=36028797.002000 Asic[03]=36028797.002000 Asic[04]=36028797.002000 Asic[05]=36028797.002000 Asic[06]=36028797.002000 Asic[07]=36028797.002000 Asic[08]=36028797.002000 
Asic[09]=36028797.002000 Asic[10]=36028797.002000 Asic[11]=36028797.002000 Asic[12]=36028797.002000 Asic[13]=36028797.002000 Asic[14]=36028797.002000 Asic[15]=36028797.002000 Asic[16]=36028797.002000 
Asic[17]=36028797.002000 Asic[18]=36028797.002000 Asic[19]=36028797.002000 Asic[20]=36028797.002000 Asic[21]=36028797.002000 Asic[22]=36028797.002000 Asic[23]=36028797.002000 Asic[24]=36028797.002000 
Asic[25]=36028797.002000 Asic[26]=36028797.002000 Asic[27]=36028797.002000 Asic[28]=36028797.002000 Asic[29]=13792138.567000 Asic[30]= 247115 Asic[31]= 141290 Asic[32]=36028797.002000 
Asic[33]=36028797.002000 Asic[34]=36028797.002000 Asic[35]= 547011 Asic[36]=1069.40 Asic[37]=18173.1 Asic[38]=117.440 Asic[39]= 227599 Asic[40]=36028797.002000 
Asic[41]=36028797.002000 Asic[42]=36028797.002000 Asic[43]=36028797.002000 Asic[44]=36028797.002000 Asic[45]=36028797.002000 Asic[46]= 277077 Asic[47]= 190215 Asic[48]=36028797.002000 
Asic[49]=36028797.002000 Asic[50]= 281273 Asic[51]=36028797.002000 Asic[52]=36028797.002000 Asic[53]=36028797.002000 Asic[54]=36028797.002000 Asic[55]=36028797.002000 Asic[56]= 176733 
Asic[57]=36028797.002000 Asic[58]=71330.8 Asic[59]=36028797.002000 Asic[60]=36028797.002000 Asic[61]=36028797.002000 Asic[62]=35747734.359000 Asic[63]=36028797.002000 
Done check_asic_reg
do read temp on Chain[5]
Chain[5] Chip[62] TempTypeID=55 middle offset=29
read failed, old value: Chain[5] Chip[62] local Temp=61
read failed on Chain[5] Chip[62] middle Temp old value:76
Special fix Chain[5] Chip[62] middle Temp = 76
Done read temp on Chain[5]
do read temp on Chain[6]
Chain[6] Chip[62] TempTypeID=55 middle offset=27
read failed, old value: Chain[6] Chip[62] local Temp=55
read failed on Chain[6] Chip[62] middle Temp old value:70
Special fix Chain[6] Chip[62] middle Temp = 70
Done read temp on Chain[6]
do read temp on Chain[7]
Chain[7] Chip[62] TempTypeID=55 middle offset=28
read failed, old value: Chain[7] Chip[62] local Temp=60
read failed on Chain[7] Chip[62] middle Temp old value:75
Special fix Chain[7] Chip[62] middle Temp = 75
Done read temp on Chain[7]
Set fixed full fan speed
FAN PWM: 100
read_temp_func Done!
CRC error counter=14833
```

I put only the end of the logs as Stack Exchange allows only 3000 characters per post, I believe the above part contains the problem

Comment: I got mine in March, and I also have that problem... Last night it wasn't mining for about 6 hours.